# R GUI with RTGK2 - choose more than one alternatives of a set of items

Tags: r, user-interface, gtk

I am trying to write my first GUI in R.
I found the package `RGtk2` which seems to work well (I am new to GTK+).

I want that the user can make a (multiple) choice out of different items. I found the following example:

```
dialog <- gtkMessageDialog(main_application_window,'destroy-with-parent','question','yes-no','Do you want to upgrade RGtk2?')
choices<-c('None','Stable version','Unstable Version')
Radio_buttons <- NULL
vbox <- gtkVBox(FALSE,0)
for(choice in choices){
+button <- gtkRadioButton(Radio_buttons,choice)
+vbox$add(button)
+radio_buttons <- c(radio_buttons,button)
}
frame <- gtkFrame('Install GTK+ System library')
frame$add(vbox)
dialog[['vbox']]$add(frame)
```

Here one can choose between 3 alternatives but the user can only mark exactely one item. How can I create something where more than one elements can be choosed?

Comment: Use check buttons (which are individually toggled) instead of radio buttons (which are supposed to allow only one option to be chosen).

Comment: Ok thank you I tried check buttons. But I have problems when adding them to the vbox (as above). How can I give the text (like above the text of choice) to the check buttons?

Comment: I presume in the same way you did above: `gtkCheckButton(choice)`. Did that not work? If not, does `gtkCheckButtonWithLabel(choice)` work?

Comment: It works with `gtkCheckButtonWithLabel`. Thanks! Another question: How can I get the items which were marked by the user? For the yes/no question there is `gtkResponseType['Yes']`. How does it work for the check buttons?

Comment: You use the `GetActive` method.